# how to access elements in lists of list in out wise in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have dynamic list that consists of lists.

```
T=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

I would like to access elements in order of `(1,4,6),(1,5,6),(2,4,6)`..

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
T=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
result = list(itertools.product(*T)) # result contains your desired list
```